# saving data from workspace to different dirrectory in matlab

Tags: matlab

I have a loop which my main script run through that. I wounder to save some of my variables in different directory every time that my loop is running. I have used following script but its not working:

```
for i=1:size(whisk, 1);

    my codes is here and it creates variables in my workspace  like [format, measurements].
    the rest is what I wote to save this variables:
    mkdir('C:\videos\results\', num2str(i));
    dumvar=0; % As matlab has problem with data>2GB, then I use this 2 line code for saving
    save('measurenments','dumvar','-v7.3');
    save(fullfile('C:\videos\results\', num2str(i),'measurenments'));
    clear all;
    close all;
end
```

but Unfortunately its not work!!!!!!!!!!!
Any help would be appreciated.
Sam

Comment: Why does it not work? Any error message? I don't understand the intention of the two calls of save.

Comment: @Daniel it just saves a file by name of measurements and format which is 7 kb, and my file is around 3 GB.

Comment: I think you have a syntax error in the code snippet. I think the argument to `fullfile` should just be the directory name and number, not `measurenments` as well. `save(fullfile('C:\videos\results\', num2str(i)),'measurenments');`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Except that measurenments is wrongly spelled (correct spelling is measurements), there is not so strange that it does not work. The first call to `save`, saves the variable `dumvar` in the current folder, with the format `v7.3`. The second call to `save`, saves the whole workspace as a file `fullfile('C:\videos\results\', num2str(i),'measurenments')`. Try this,

```
save(fullfile('C:\videos\results\', num2str(i),'measurenments'),'dumvar','-v7.3');
```

However it seems as the folder `fullfile('C:\videos\results\', num2str(i),'measurenments')` does not exist since you only create the folder `mkdir('C:\videos\results\', num2str(i))`
. Then matlab cannot save anything there. Try either to save as `fullfile('C:\videos\results\', [num2str(i),'measurenments'])` or create the directory `mkdir('C:\videos\results\', [num2str(i),'\','measurenments']);`
`

Comment: thanks. it was helpful tips from you which helped me.